# Difference of singleton injection methods in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

What's the difference between these injection methods?

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMyClass, MyClass>());

services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Was there some part there which wasn’t clear about their usage and you’d need clarification?

Comment: I can't find their difference @SamiKuhmonen?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMyClass, MyClass>());
> ```

Tries to register `IMyClass`, if its already registered, nothing will happen and the previous registration remains the only one. This results in one `IMyClass` registration.

> ```
> services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
> ```

Will register `IMyClass` anyways, even if there is a different registration already such as `<IMyClass, DefaultMyClass>`. This results in two `IMyClass` registrations.

The difference comes, when using `provider.GetService`/`provider.GetRequriedService` or injecting `IMyClass` vs `IEnumerable<IMyClass>`.

When using `provider.GetService`/`provider.GetRequriedService` or injecting `IMyClass`, the last registration will be used (correct me if wrong, can't find the reference/GitHub issue on the quick).

So if you had

```
 services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, DefaultMyClass>();
 services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

`MyClass` instance will be returned when resolved.

Whereas

```
 services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, DefaultMyClass>();
 services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMyClass, MyClass>());
```

would return `DefaultMyClass`, because `<IMyClass,MyClass>` would not be registered.

On the other side, when you use `provider.GetServices(...)` (notice the plural version, with an **s** at the end) or inject `IEnumerable<IMyClass>`, then you would return both instance when using

```
 services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, DefaultMyClass>();
 services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

and you could iterate over them.